# Limit of implicitely defined function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

I have this implicit equation $F(x, y) = x^2y+e^{x+y} = 0 $. Now this defines a function $y=f(x)$ everywhere except for $x=0$. I need to compute the limit for $x \rightarrow 0^+$.

I know that $y = -\dfrac{e^{x+y}}{x^2} < 0$ and that $y' = - \dfrac{2xy + e^{x+y}}{x^2+ e^{x+y}} $

But I cannot imagine how to compute the right handed limit in question. I know that $y(0^+)$ cannot be a constant else there would be a contradiction. But what if $y$ oscillates? How can I exclude this and be sure that the limit is $-\infty$? Thanks for tips.

Comment: As written your function is not implicitly defined. You just wrote a function of two variables $F(x,y)$. Do you perhaps mean $F = 0$ is the implicit equation?

Comment: Yes sorry. Fixed.

Comment: I thought about this some, and it would be helpful if you could elaborate on the contradiction you run into. I have an idea for how you could prove it, but I don't know what you already have or if it'll work. Roughly, it's to replace the limit at $0$ of $y'$ with the $\liminf$. If this number was finite, you'd have a lower bound on the derivative, which can't exist if you're going to $-\infty$ in finite time. OTOH, liminf can't fail to exist due to oscillation, because it can only increase as you go further out the sequence.

Comment: The contradiction is in the definition of the function if the limit was a (negative or $0$) constant $c=y(0^+)=-\dfrac{e^c}{0^+} = -\infty$. Also it is not possible for $y$ to stay bounded for the same reason. But $y$ could oscillate between say a value and $-\infty$ in theory.

Comment: Another thing that would rule out oscillation is if the derivative only had a finite amount of zeros, thing that I do not know how to prove, or if $y\prime\prime$ was negative for $x > 0$, still no idea how.

Comment: Oh I think I got it. $y\prime = - \dfrac{2xy + e^{x+y} \pm x^2y}{x^2+ e^{x+y}}=-\dfrac{xy(2-x)}{x^2+ e^{x+y}}$ since we are on the level curve. Now there is a single zero in the derivative so no oscillations.

Comment: Just a $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ remark: either `y^{\prime}` or, more simply `y'`. For the second derivative, either `y^{\prime\prime}` or the definitely simpler `y''`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rewrite the derivative using $y=-e^{x+y}/x^2$, you get
$$
y'=\frac{(2-x)e^{x+y}}{x(x^2+e^{x+y})}
$$
which is positive in a right neighborhood of $0$. Thus your function is increasing in such a neighborhood and therefore the limit exists, either finite or $-\infty$.

Now show that a finite limit leads to a contradiction.